# APS Inventor Design Automatiion Failed Instructions

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

I'm trying to modify a model built using iLogic in Inventor 2023 using APS Design Automation.
But I'm getting Failed Instructions in the status and not sure with the reason. Please find the reports in the snapshots.

[Failed Instructions Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAduv.png)

[Success Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTQIC.png)

[Failed log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtLSD.jpg)

[Success Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCUH0.jpg)

Both the success logs and failed logs have iLogic errors but Success status still does the required work. Even in the failed case, the SVF is translated but the upload Phase after iLogic Diagnostics hasn't started. My expectation is that even if there are iLogic errors, the errors should be suppresed and should succeed.

Somebody please correct me if I'm wrong or do share my any hack to suppress these iLogic errors if that's the reason for Failedinstructions.

Comment: You will need to share the snippets from the log. The links are valid only for a certain time and as of now the ones you shared have expired.

Comment: Thankyou @RahulBhobe .  Just edited and added the snippets.

Answer (score 0):

From the log snippet above it seems like you are trying to run ExternalRule. It is not visible there what is exact reason as image is not whole. I would guess the ExternalRule is not available (as it is external file).

Comment: Is there any way to suppress these errors?

Comment: Do you mean if there is a way how to ignore that Inventor tries to execute external rule which doesn't exists? I don't think it is possible, or even good idea.

Are you able to edit iLogic inside your Inventor files? Or is it that you cannot affect these Inventor files and you would like to make them work even though they are trying to call external rules?

I would recommend either edit Inventor file so it doesn't call external rule, or bundle the external rule as part of your inputs so Inventor file can access them.

Comment: The external rule errors are available even in the logs of a successful run. That's what made me curious. The difference I found comparing both the logs was that in the failure case the Upload Phase didn't begin while Processing failed in both the cases. So I just thought maybe there's some other problem.

Comment: In logs you attached, I don't see external rule processing error.

Comment: Have added the snippets in the edit

Comment: In one of the failed reports I can see there were other issues as well related to iLogicForm. Could you provide the full report file for a work item that failed and one that succeeded - both including the External Rule error?
If you don't want to share it publicly, you can reach out to us on aps.help@autodesk.com